# For Loop With Negative Percentage & Values

Tags: jquery

This is probably obvious but I can't seem to figure it out.  I'm trying to write a for loop to do my select box values and I need the data to be represented as a percentage.  So for instance my first option should have a value of '-0.10' and loop to '1.00'.  The options themselves should have a value of '-10%' to '100%'.  Obviously my code is bad but I'm having trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong. So far I have this:

```
$(function(){
    var $select = $(".nextYearFTEGrowth");
    for (i=-10;i<=100;i++){
        for (j=-.10;j<=1.00;j++){
            $select.append($('<option></option>').html(i).val(j))
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BTrPr/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made some changes below, improving readability, code length and desired results:

```
$(function(){
    var $select = $(".nextYearFTEGrowth");
    for (i=-10;i<=100;i++)
    {
        $select.append($('<option>').text(i+"%").val(i/100))
    }
});
```

As you can see I've shortened the `<option></option>` to just `<option>` - mainly saving code length. I've also removed the inner `for` loop as it was only there for creating a decimal (and wrongly), so I've just set the val as the `number/100`, which is how you get from a percentage to a decimal representation (assuming that's what you were after)

See it in action on a [new jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BTrPr/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Your answer screams IT guy with a dirty stache yelling "MOVE IDIOT!".  EDIT: now your edits make it not seem so bad.

Comment: @Chad No worries, apologies if I sounded abrasive, it honestly wasn't meant to be - I was purely making statements. I've reworded my introducing line anyway (assuming that's the offensive one!) as the part about jQuery isn't true now that I've updated the link in your question.

Comment: How about adding a percentage tag to the end of the string?

Comment: @Chad Just append the `i` in `text()` with `+"%"` - see updated answer.

Comment: Ah ok, I was really close.  Still learning this stuff.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Chad No worries. Remember that you can click the tick icon under the voting arrows to say that this answer has solved your problem - this tells future visitors that it's already sorted and how it was done. Happy coding!

Comment: Yeah, sorry it was making me wait to check it off and just forgot.  I'll check it now. Thanks again.